# % string formatting doesn't work in class methods? (ruby)

Tags: ruby, methods, string-formatting

any idea how I can display **headers** using % for formatting? I does nothing in class method but works nicely in instance method

```
class Stats
 attr_accessor :type, :count;
 def initialize type
   @type = type
   @count = 0
 end


 def self.display
   "%s %4s  " % ["header1",'header2']
   #puts 'headers'
   ObjectSpace.each_object(Stats) { |o|
  puts o
   }
 end


 def to_s
   "%-9s %4d " % [@type, @count]
 end
end

videos = Stats.new 'Videos'
videos.count = 3
article = Stats.new 'Article'
webinars = Stats.new 'Webinars'

Stats.display
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not printing out the result of calling `%` in `self.display`, which is why you're not seeing the headers. Try doing the following instead:

```
def self.display
  puts "%s %4s  " % ["header1", "header2"]

  ObjectSpace.each_object(Stats) {|o| puts o }
end
```

You could also use [`printf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005951), which does the formatting and printing:

```
def self.display
  printf "%s %4s  \n", "header1", "header2"

  ObjectSpace.each_object(Stats) {|o| puts o }
end
```

Comment: @Phil Ross: what's the emoticon for blushing? :-) Thank you